# Determinant of a matrix with binomial coefficients.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, binomial-coefficients, problem-solving

Let $n \in\mathbb{N}$ and $A=(a_{ij})$ where 
\begin{equation}a_{ij}=\binom{i+j}{i}\end{equation}
for $0\leq i,j \leq n$. Show that $A$ has an inverse and that every element of $A^{-1}$ is an integer.

I have shown that this $n\times n$ matrix is symmetric since, 
\begin{equation}
\binom{i+j}{i}=\binom{i+j}{j}
\end{equation} 
in order to try to get a nonzero determinant. 
But i'm stuck in this step, suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, is $A$ an $n \times n$ matrix or an $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix?

Comment: One route is to take the augmented matrix $[A,I]$ and use elementary row operations to obtain $[I,A^{-1}]$. This may seem tedious, but it can be made much more efficient by implementing them as matrix multiplications (compare with Wikipedia's page on [elementary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix).  From what I can see, this obtains $A^{-1}$ as a LU decomposition in integral matrices. (I write this as a comment, because even in this form it's a bit tedious.)

Answer (score 4):

There's a usually useless formula for the matrix inverse [in terms of cofactors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html). It's actually useful here. The elements $b_{ij}$ of the matrix inverse are explicitely given by:

$$b_{ij}=\frac{|C_{ij}|}{|A|},$$

where $C_{ij}$ is the cofactor matrix. Show by a method of your choice, such as induction, that $|A|=1$, for all $n$. Then the answer is clear because $|C_{ij}|$ is just a sum of integer products.

Comment: While I agree with the substance of this answer, I have to quibble with that formula being 'usually useless': it amounts to an application of Cramer's rule, which (while computationally ineffective as a way to compute an inverse) does have quite a few applications (see this earlier [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/751089/137524) for a few examples).

Comment: Can you give a hint on how to prove that $\det A = 1$? I can't find a good way to run induction here.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a particular case (say $n=5$) and you consider the [LDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#LDL_decomposition) or Cholesky decomposition of this matrix you notice something very interesting: ( [WA link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LUDecomposition%5BTable%5B%20Binomial%5B%20i%2Bj%2C%20j%5D%2C%20%7Bi%2C0%2C5%7D%2C%20%7Bj%2C0%2C5%7D%5D%5D)).

So one should try to prove that our matrix $A$ is the product
$$A = L \cdot L^t$$
where
$L = (\binom{i}{j})_{0\le i,j \le n}$.This translates into the equalities:
$$\sum_k\binom{i}{k}  \binom{j}{k} = \sum_k\binom{i}{k}  \binom{j}{j-k}= \binom{i+j}{j}$$

Note that $L$ is lower triangular with $1$ on the diagonal, so invertible. In fact, its inverse can be explicitely given
$$L^{-1} = ((-1)^{i-k} \binom{i}{j})$$
One can prove a more general equality
$$L^{a}\cdot L^{b}=L^{a+b}$$
where $L_{ij}^a =a^{i-j} \binom{i}{j}$.

So now we get
$$A^{-1} = (L\cdot L^t)^{-1}= (L^{-1})^t \cdot L^{-1}$$
so clearly with integral elements, although I can't notice a particularly nice form for the entries.

Notice: matrices of the form $\binom{a+i+j}{j}$, or $\binom{a+i}{j}$, or $\binom{a-i}{j}$, or more generally, $\binom{a \pm i + b j}{j}$ also have nice LU decompositions. ($a$, $b$  parameters). The L part (the lower triangular part) is always $\binom{i}{j}$.